# Find the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{x+1} $ at $x=2$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

This is what I did:

$\begin{align*}
f(x)&=&(x+1)^{-1}\\
f'(x)&=&-(x+1)^{-2}\\
f''(x)&=&2(x+1)^{-3}\\
f'''(x)&=&-6(x+1)^{-4}\\
f''''(x)&=&24(x+1)^{-5}\\
&\vdots\\
f^{(n)}(x)&=&(-1)^nn!(x+1)^{-(n+1)}
\end{align*}$

Then I substituted $x=2$:

$f^{(n)}(2)=(-1)^nn!(2+1)^{-(n+1)}=(-1)^nn!(3)^{-(n+1)} $

Then I put it all together.

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x+1}&= &\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(2)}{n!}(x-2)\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nn!(3)^{-(n+1)}}{n!}(x-2)\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(3)^{-(n+1)}(x-2)
\end{align*}

I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Another approach: You know the series for $\frac{1}{1-t}$. Your function is $\frac{1}{3+(x-2)}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x-2}{3}}$. Let $t=-\frac{x-2}{3}$.

Answer (score 3):

Almost perfect. You should have $(x-2)^n$, rather than just $(x-2)$, in your sums. It might also behoove you to indicate for which $x$ the series is equal to the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach mentioned by Andre:

$$\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{1}{3+(x-2)}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x-2}{3}}=\frac{1}{3}\left(1-\frac{x-2}{3}+\left(\frac{x-2}{3}\right)^2-\ldots\right)=$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{x-2}{3}\right)^n$$

The above being true whenever

$$\left|\frac{x-2}{3}\right|<1\Longleftrightarrow |x-2|<3\Longleftrightarrow -1<x<5$$

which is a reasonable assumption as we want $\,x\,$ to be "close" to $\,2\,$ ("close" may be in the eyes of the beholder...)